# GoogleAnalyticsTracker javadoc

Tags: android, google-analytics

Where can I find the javadoc for Google Analytics for Android? I searched for it on the [project homepage](http://code.google.com/mobile/analytics/docs/android/), but couldn't find it anywhere.

Comment: I'm not sure one exists.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: almost every method is used and described in some detail on the site - is there something specific you are looking for?

Comment: @bizso09 i'm only asking because there does not appear to be one, but if you have a specific question some may be able to give you a specific answer :)

Comment: I am kinda in the same boat. The main features are in the sample code supplied but I just want to know what options there are for me. There are lots of tracker methods such as `setDryRun()`. I assume its just flags which will show up somewhere on the analytics site. I just don't know what they do and am curious.

Answer (score 6):

You can find the Google Analytics for Android javadocs in the "javadocs.zip" file in the "GoogleAnalyticsAndroid.zip" file, which the "libGoogleAnalyticsV2.jar" comes within.
Download it [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/resources).

Answer (score 1):

There is a Google Code page for Anaylytics, it shows you how to use the API. [Analytics-api-sample](http://code.google.com/p/analytics-api-samples/source/browse/#svn/trunk/javadocs). You will probably have to check it out from SVN to use it.

Answer (score 1):

You can generate it out of the API
Here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-jsp-135444.html

Answer (score 1):

Javadoc for Google Analytics v4 is available here:

https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/analytics/package-summary.html

Full Doc for Android Google Analytics is here:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/

Answer (score 0):

The closest I have come to documentation is from the ReadMe.txt from EasyTrackerAndroid_1.0.zip  found [here](https://code.google.com/p/analytics-api-samples/downloads/list).

Excerpt from the ReadMe:

```
ga_api_key (String) - the account ID used for tracking.  You need this set for
                      EasyTracker to start tracking your application.

ga_debug (Bool) - Set to true if you wish to see debug messages from the
                  GoogleAnalytics library in the Android log. Default is false.

ga_dryRun (Bool) - Set to true if you want to test your tracking code without
                   actually sending data to Google Analytics. Default is false.

ga_anonymizeIp (Bool) - Set to true to remove the last octet of the device's IP
                        Address from tracking data.  Default is false.

ga_sampleRate(Integer) - Set to a number between 0 and 100, inclusive.  Zero
                         will turn off all tracking while 100 will have every
                         application instance track.  Any number in between will
                         limit the number of application instances that actually
                         send tracking data to approximately that percentage.
                         Default is 100.

ga_dispatchPeriod (Integer) - Set to the time period in seconds to wait between
                              dispatches. Setting to zero will turn off
                              automatic dispatching.  Default is 60.

ga_auto_activity_tracking (Bool) - Set to true to track time spent in each
                                   Activity.  Set to false to track application-
                                   level information only.  Default is false.
```