# Google Analytics (GA) send call with simple params on Android don't show results in dashboard

Tags: android, google-analytics

I run the following code but see nothing in the [reporting section of GA](https://www.google.com/analytics/web/).

```
HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put("View start", "MenuActivity");
Application.getGaTracker().send(map);
```

BUT, when executing a "built-in" event, I do see results. Example:

```
Application.getGaTracker().send(MapBuilder.createAppView().set(Fields.SCREEN_NAME, "Main").build());
```

Why is a simple params send isn't working?

EDIT: I use GAv3 SDK for Android.

Comment: What does it mean when you send a map that you created with `new HashMap`? Doesn't it have to be created using `MapBuilder.createAppView()`?

Comment: @gnobal - from Tracker javadocs: `public void send(java.util.Map<java.lang.String,java.lang.String> params)`. API states that I can use any map I want.

Comment: I couldn't find the javadoc on the web - it was provided with the SDK jar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I missed is the `Fields.HIT_TYPE` key and the mandatory params based on the hit type.
Example:

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put(Fields.HIT_TYPE, com.google.analytics.tracking.android.HitTypes.EVENT);
map.put(Fields.EVENT_CATEGORY, "UX");
map.put(Fields.EVENT_ACTION, "screen_view");
Application.getGaTracker().send(map);
```

See more [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v3/events) and [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v3/screens) for some of the hit types params. Some of the params are mandatory and some optional.

This reminds me very much of javascript API, where everything can be changed and nothing is enforced in the API. Also, the hit type is very implicit.

For conclusion, this basic `Tracker.send(...)` API is so implicit and non-descriptive - deserves the definition crap!

I understand if Google keeps this API for backward or cross-language compatibility.
What I don't understand is why Google chose not to create a decent descriptive API and deprecate this generic, implicit, non-descriptive, crappy API.

Even the new `MapBuilder.createEvent(...)` API doesn't explain what is mandatory and optional, nor enforces it in code.

Another issue is that the GAv3AndroidSdk doesn't give any feedback if something isn't working. Only now did I see that there is a warning in the logcat about a missing param, which only divine beings would understand it's meaning: `Missing hit type (&t) parameter`. Why is this a warning and not an ERROR??? If an event was requested to be sent and eventually did not sent, it's an ERROR!!! Also, why not say that the request was not performed??? This logcat feedback is too implicit and elusive.

Rant finished.

Comment: Does someone knows where's the GA Android SDK v3 javadoc can be found online? I'd like to add the links to the answer.

Comment: I am also confused by the GA API for Android. Thanks for sharing your thoughts.
Regarding the location of the API docs, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7491564/googleanalyticstracker-javadoc.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v3/advanced#set-send) you can only use supported keys, specified as constants of the `Fields` class:

```
Tracker tracker = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this).getTracker("UA-XXXX-Y");

HashMap<String, String> hitParameters = new HashMap<String, String>();
hitParameters.put(Fields.HIT_TYPE, com.google.analytics.tracking.android.HitTypes.APP_VIEW);
hitParameters.put(Fields.SCREEN_NAME, "Home Screen");

tracker.send(hitParameters);
```

But as they say:

> The `MapBuilder` class simplifies the process of building hits and is
>   recommended for most use cases.